# jQuery dynamic ui element creation

Tags: php, jquery, dynamic, user-interface

This is my first time using jQuery (I'm familiar with Java) and I've followed some tutorials online to understand draggables/droppables and events etc.

The context is a simple interactive game where the user drags multiple items into categories.
What I want to know is, is it possible to dynamically create a number of objects, which can be draggable, the number of which determined from a php script before the main page loads? Like a constructor in Java terms?

Any help or direction would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it's very easy to create elements using jQuery. For example, the below code will create a new `div` element:

```
var $div = $("<div></div>").appendTo("body");
```

To make this element draggable, you need to include [jQueryUI](http://jqueryui.com/) in your page and then call [`draggable()`](http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable/) on it:

```
$div.draggable();
```

[**Working example**](http://jsfiddle.net/c6Pz6/)

Comment: May be simplified to `$('<div/>')` as well.

Comment: I've read that it's better to explicitly include the relevant closing tag, should one exist, for better browser compatibility. This was a while ago now, so may no longer be the case with the latest version of jQ.

Comment: Yes I thought so. Just expressing my syntactic sugar liking. `=]` Even just `$("<div>")` would work as well but writing valid XML is advisable. Time to read the source a bit.

Comment: Looking through the [source](http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.2.js)'s `// Handle HTML strings` block's regex which matches single tag html strings: `rsingleTag = /^<(\w+)\s*\/?>(?:<\/\1>)?$/` returns the same first capturing group for `$("<div>")`, `$("<div/>")` and `$("<div></div>")` which is passed to a `document.createElement` call. Who'd say, `$("<div>")` is completed valid as well.

Comment: Thank you very much Rory, going to work on a way now to accept an int from a php script to determine the number of divs.